# Facebook Tab / Page Authentication issues: getLoginStatus always returns not_authorized

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the following code for my Facebook Application:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXXX', // App ID
      channelUrl : '/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here

        //***************************************************
        //* FanGate for Facebook
        //***************************************************
        var hideLogin = function(){
           $("#login-fb").hide();
        }

        var showLogin = function(){
           $("#login-fb").show();
        }

        var doLogin = function(){
            FB.login(function(response) {
              if (response.session) {
                   hideLogin();
                   checkLike(response.session.uid)
              } else {
                // user is not logged in
              }
            });
        }

        var checkLike = function(user_id){
            var page_id = "XXXXXXXXX"; //coca cola
            var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
            var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);

                  the_query.wait(function(rows) {

                      if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                          $("#thirsty_thursdays").show();                  
                      } else {
                          $("#fan_gate").show();
                      }
                  });        
        }


        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            console.log(response.status);
            if (response.status == 'connected') {
                hideLogin();
                checkLike(response.authResponse.userID)
            } else {
                showLogin();
            }
        }, true);

        $("#login-fb a").click(doLogin);    
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
```

`response.status` always returns `not_authorized` and I am really unclear why.  I am logged into Facebook and the application is a simple Page Tab. I have recently added App on Facebook to the setting to see if that helps but no luck.

I have not seen any additional info on the Facebook JS SDK docs that give any info.

I am basically looking to show content if the user is logged in and is a fan of a certain page and hide the content if not. (commonly called fan gate)

Answer (score 0):

Would have posted this as a comment but I cant yet...

After your tab loads and the FB.getLoginStatus() response indicates "not_authorized" (and therefore, I assume, shows your login button) -- what happens if you then click your login button?  Is it giving the facebook pop-up prompt to authorize the app? (I'm hesitant to ask this but are you in fact sure that you've authorized the app?)   Or does it just do nothing?

-In the callback for FB.login..  what does it output if you add a console.log(response.authResponse)     ?

-I believe the channelUrl is supposed to be fully qualified whereas you have it root relative..  Not sure that would have any impact on your issue but might want to try it..  see  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/#channel